# Cannot curl EC2 instance - Connection refused on port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc, aws-security-group

So I have two instances, instance A is part of a security group sg-1 and instance B is part of another security group sg-2.

sg-1 has settings to allow all outbound traffic
sg-2 has settings to allow traffic from sg-1 on port 80, 9200 and 9300:

[image]

Yet, when I SSH onto instance A and try to curl instance B on port 9200, I get an error: `Failed to connect to <Instance B Private IP> port 80: Connection refused`

Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You say " curl instance B on port 9200" but the error says port 80. Which is it?

Comment: It's 9200 sorry, but it doesn't work for port 80 either despite having set that inbound rule (shown in screenshot).

Comment: Are services actually listening on those ports on instance B?

Comment: Yup, elastic search running on 9200. However nothing on 80 though

Comment: If you temporarily open port 9200 to the world, can you curl to it from your own computer? If you login to instance-B, can you `curl localhost:9200`?